# Is there a way to call json parameters explicitly?

Tags: python, json

I'm writing program using OpenWeatherMap and I have JSON file about weather:

Is there a way to save info from `"main":{"temp":...` explicitly or is the way I did the only one?

```
{"coord":
    {"lon":145.77,"lat":-16.92},
    "weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04n"}],
    "base":"cmc stations",
    "main":{"temp":293.25,"pressure":1019,"humidity":83,"temp_min":289.82,"temp_max":295.37},
    "wind":{"speed":5.1,"deg":150},
    "clouds":{"all":75},
    "rain":{"3h":3},
    "dt":1435658272,
    "sys":{"type":1,"id":8166,"message":0.0166,"country":"AU","sunrise":1435610796,"sunset":1435650870},
    "id":2172797,
    "name":"Cairns",
    "cod":200}
```

Code:

```
response = resp.json()
if response['cod'] != '404':
    main_json = response['main']
    temperature = main_json['temp']
```

Comment: Don't you need to start with `response = resp.json()['coord']`?

Comment: If this is from `requests` you should be able to do `resp.raise_for_status()` in a `try/except` rather than manually checking the status code

Comment: please give us the rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

By explicitly do you mean directly?

```
temperature = response['main']['temp']
```

Edit:

After saving your json to a file called data.json, the following code works on my machine:

```
import json

with open('data.json') as json_file:
    response = json.load(json_file)

if response['cod'] != '404':
    main_json = response['main']['temp']
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this and it doesn't work

    temperature = response['main']['temp']
KeyError: 'main'

Comment: Then how does `main_json = response['main']` in your question work?

Comment: I don't know why

Comment: @PawełDługosz It is not possible for `main_json = response['main']` to work, but fail when replaced with `main_json = response['main']['temp']` with the reason `KeyError: 'main'`. Is it possible that you changed something else that is causing this problem?

Comment: Yeah, you were right, it doesn't work, i had problems with json

Comment: @PawełDługosz glad to hear that you solved this. If you ever need to check the validity of some json, this is a useful tool: https://jsonlint.com/